# Loading animations native in chrome & other browsers -> is it possible to disable them?

Tags: html, css, web

Take this website for example: https://resn.co.nz/#!/work/all

Typically when you develop a website and deploy, when you browse from page to page this triggers a loading animation, either a circle or a progress bar that sweeps across the tab pane at the top of your browser. This example website doesn't have this.

I have smooth loading animations on my portfolio so that it shouldn't feel like you're switching from one page to another per-say. How can I get rid of the animation flickers across browsers as in the example above? Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

The page you shared in the example is actually a SPA, I recommend you to research about this term.

Basically, SPA is a web app which actually fits on a single webpage providing a great user experience and loading everything's that is needed on that first page. It is also ideal for a rich user experience which keeps the user really engaged in the application by keeping the pages moving fluently because of the client side navigation and just as important as the other two is reduced round tripping which means they'll make less trips between the client and server and less post backs of the entire page.